# How to configure FFMPEG with Xampp in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, ffmpeg, xampp

Hi i am i trying to merge videos using ffmpeg with Php.Now i installed Xampp in ubuntu.and FFMEPG also i installed in Ubuntu.I searched ffmpeg.dll file but its not dound in the directory.but i add the extension in the php.ini file like below my code

```
 ;extension=php_bz2.dll
 ;extension=php_ffmpeg.dll
 ;extension=php_curl.dll
 ;extension=php_dba.dll
 ;extension=php_exif.dll
 ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

This is my test code for ffmpeg.

```
     <?php
    extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');
    $vid = realpath('1.mp4');
   $ffmpegInstance = new ffmpeg_movie($vid);
    echo "getDuration: " . $ffmpegInstance->getDuration() . "<br />".
   "getFrameCount: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameCount() . "<br />".
   "getFrameRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameRate() . "<br />".
   "getFilename: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFilename() . "<br />".
   "getComment: " . $ffmpegInstance->getComment() . "<br />".
   "getTitle: " . $ffmpegInstance->getTitle() . "<br />".
   "getAuthor: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAuthor() . "<br />".
   "getCopyright: " . $ffmpegInstance->getCopyright() . "<br />".
   "getArtist: " . $ffmpegInstance->getArtist() . "<br />".
   "getGenre: " . $ffmpegInstance->getGenre() . "<br />".
   "getTrackNumber: " . $ffmpegInstance->getTrackNumber() . "<br />".
   "getYear: " . $ffmpegInstance->getYear() . "<br />".
   "getFrameHeight: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameHeight() . "<br />".
   "getFrameWidth: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameWidth() . "<br />".
   "getPixelFormat: " . $ffmpegInstance->getPixelFormat() . "<br />".
   "getBitRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getBitRate() . "<br />".
   "getVideoBitRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getVideoBitRate() . "<br />".
   "getAudioBitRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioBitRate() . "<br />".
   "getAudioSampleRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioSampleRate() . "<br />".
   "getVideoCodec: " . $ffmpegInstance->getVideoCodec() . "<br />".
   "getAudioCodec: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioCodec() . "<br />".
   "getAudioChannels: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioChannels() . "<br />".
   "hasAudio: " . $ffmpegInstance->hasAudio();?>
```

When i run this in xammp the output coming like this

Error in loading ffmpeg

kindly give some solution for me 
thanks in advance.

Comment: ffmpeg is not a php or apache module. FFmpeg is a standalone command line tool. But there is a php-ffmpeg module on github.

Comment: To enable a module you need to remove the semicolon in the php.ini `extension=php_ffmpeg.dll`.

Comment: Is we can use in php or not Dunois.Is there any other solution to merge two videos in programatic

Comment: Like I said there is on github a php module for ffmpeg (in the debian repos too, btw). But you can't use it with PHP 5.5. I don't know about the ubuntu repos.

Comment: Thanks Dunios I ll search on github